# Separate labels in cases

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, cases

As much as I have tried, it doesn't seem possible to use separate labels when using a `cases`construction (from the `amsmath` package).

Ideally, I would like to be able to write something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
  1&x\geq0\label{positive}\\
  0&x<0\label{negative}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and later refer to both cases at different places. What would be the best way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `numcases` from [the `cases` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cases) if you want each case labelled as a separate equation. There is also the `subnumcases` environment which gives you an alternative labelling:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
\begin{numcases}{f(x)=}
   1 & $x\geq0$ \label{positive}
   \\
   0 & $x<0$ \label{negative}
\end{numcases}

See the second case \ref{negative} or the first \ref{positive}

\begin{subnumcases}{f(x)=}
   1 & $x\geq0$ \label{positive-subnum}
   \\
   0 & $x<0$ \label{negative-subnum}
\end{subnumcases}

See the second case \ref{negative-subnum} or the first \ref{positive-subnum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Worth mentioning is the `subnum` package option that turns every `numcases` environment into a `subnumcases` one.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the option `preview` to the `\documentclass` instruction. The default behavior of the `standalone` document class has changed since 2011, and your MWE won't compile correctly any longer without the `preview` option.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use this method for a 'dcase' envirinment?

Comment: @FahimB: Good question. I don't know but would recommend you post a new question and link to this one as it is very much related.

Answer (score 23):

Using only the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and no additional packages, it is possible with some box manipulation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mycases}% Store case "title" and brace
\begin{align}
  \sbox{\mycases}{$\displaystyle f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\vphantom{1\ x\geq0}\\\vphantom{0\ x<0}\end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$}
  \raisebox{-.5\ht\mycases}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox{\mycases}}1 \quad x\geq0\label{positive} \\
     0 \quad x<0\label{negative}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your method has the virtue of producing `\label`s that are handled correctly by `\cref` (of the `cleveref` package) cross-referencing commands, whereas the solution produced by the `cases` package -- see @PeterGrill's parallel answer -- does not.

Comment: Also, it's compatible with the `refcheck` package, as opposed the `subnumcases` solution.

Answer (score 19):

You can do this by the [empheq](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package from the [mh](http://ctan.org/pkg/mh) bundle.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{empheq}   % loads »mathtools«, which in turn loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \begin{empheq}[left={f(x)=\empheqlbrace}]{align}
    1 &\quad x\geq0\label{positive}\\
    0 &\quad x<0\label{negative}
  \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The good, if brief, is twice good!

Answer (score 18):

You can combine [the preceding solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31954/125558) with the `subequations` environment if you refer to the equations as a group. If you want to refer to the group, you have to introduce a \label just before entering the `align` environment. Here it is in action:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{cleveref} 

 \begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{Phi:def}
  \begin{align}[left ={Φ(A_n) = \empheqlbrace}]
    & \max \left [ L_n-A_n, 0 \right]\\
    & \max \left [ L_n-A_n, K \right]\label{eq:PayoffStopLosses}\\
    & \max \left [ L_n-A_n, K_1 \right] -\max \left [ A_n-L_n, K_2 \right]
   \end{align}
  \end{subequations}

As we can see in \cref{Phi:def}, and more specifically in \cref{eq:PayoffStopLosses},…

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: useful concept.  please show what references (`\eqref`) would look like, for the group as a whole, and for one or more of the subequations.