# Separate labels in cases 2

Tags: cross-referencing, cases

Is there a cases package that lets me label my cases as I want? The `cases` and `subcases` environments of the `cases` package either labels tags with consecutive numbers or not at all. I would like some cases labeled and some not.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [separate labels in cases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases/31956#31956). You can add `\nonumber` if you don't want an equation labelled.

Comment: You can also try the **empheq** package, as shown in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases/31954#31954); the environment behaves like `align`, so accepts `\label` and `\nonumber`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\nonumber` to suppress the tag:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{leftside}
  case1 & explanation1 \nonumber\\
  case2 & explanation2 \\
  case3 & explanation3 \nonumber\\
  case4 & explanation4
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]