# How can I use a curly brace together with subequations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, braces, subequations

The code

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x+y=2 \\
x-y=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

produces two aligned equations, with a curly brace to the left. I want to refer to the individual equations, and the subequations environment looks right. However when I try using it, I can't find a way to leave that curly brace on the left.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: See (duplicate) [Separate labels in cases 2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34399/5764). You can use the `numcases` environment from [`cases`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cases).

Comment: Thank you! This way they are numbered only, but I want them all to have a number followed by a letter (a,b,c,...) like \subequations does. Is this possible?

Comment: There's `subnumcases` then, also provided by [`cases`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cases). See [Separate labels in `cases`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951/5764).