# How can I label for a collection of equations?

Tags: equations, numbering, cases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate labels in cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases)

I want to label each equation in a collection of equations as in the example below. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: The question as you asked it is a bit difficult to understand, more so because I don't have the courage to download the PDF from the link you inserted. And probably no one sane would... Try to insert the content as a picture.

Comment: I was crazy enough to do so.  It is a `cases` environment, with each line numbered.  I'm still not sure what the question is asking, though.

Comment: Dear Andrew Uzzell, you understand me.

Comment: It seems quite unusual to assign separate equation numbers to various parts of a `cases` environment. Could you just refer to lines 1, 2, or 3 of the (single) equation rendered as a `cases` environment?

Comment: I guess that `subnumcases` would be the answer. On the other hand, if you need to refer to all the lines, it's probably better to use only *one* number for the whole equation. After all, it's the definition of *one* function; what does (1) refer to? To "0", to "if x>0" or to both?

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases) help?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\eqref{eq:first}-\eqref{eq:last}` if you are using the `amsmath` package and `(\ref{eq:first})-(\ref{eq:last})` if you do not use it.