# align nested in cases

Tags: align, cases

#### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subnumcases}{}\label{eq:regola_scelta_reject}
    \begin{aligned}
    objective   &: \qquad \min \quad \sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j\\
    subject to  &: \qquad \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j \geq W_L\\
    \end{aligned} \label{eq:regola_scelta_reject_1}\\
    \begin{aligned}
    objective   &: \qquad \min \quad \sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j \vee H_{e} \geq 2 \\  
    subject to  &: \qquad \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j < W_L\\
    \end{aligned} \label{eq:regola_scelta_reject_2}\\
\end{subnumcases}
\end{document}
```

What I'm doing wrong? This is what I'm trying to acheive:

[image: Example]

Comment: Please always post complete documents. Without effort it is hard to see what you have done wrong as we can't see the output or error message without reconstructing a document that you presumably have already.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fixed. The fact is that `cases`request 2 condition on the same line. Is there any alternative to `cases`that doesn't include the 2-nd condition?

Comment: surrounding the `cases` environment in dollar signs will remove the particular errors you are experiencing, but there are other issues, such as material you intend as text being placed into math style.

Comment: Also, when David suggests that "complete documents" should be posted, he means something that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @gmeroni as Steven says that isn't a usable document.

Comment: cases is a math environment so put it inside `\[....\]`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ok. My request is how can i obtain [this](http://cl.ly/image/0l311h043V1t/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-13%20at%2015.14.46.png)

Comment: It is called a MWE (minimum working example), and you are asked to construct it, so that we who are willing to help you don't have to guess as to what you might be trying to accomplish (TeX speaks louder than words).  While some errors are straightforward, others are subtle and depend on an interaction of the various packages that are loaded, or what class you are using.  Asking you to build an MWE may take a little of your time, but that is more polite and efficient than asking a multitude here to all build a version of your MWE ourselves, for your benefit.  We have day jobs too.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The fact is: I font have a WORKING example...I don't know if I have to use `subnumcases`, `cases`, `align`, `equino`, ecc ecc...so I can't construct a MWE

Comment: Even if your MWE doesn't work, you can construct a small version "that doesn't work" that begins with `\documentclass` etc.  An accompanying picture helps, preferably viewable in your question, rather than to a website that is blocked by my browser.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Initial question updated.

Comment: Indeed, that is now a real question.

Comment: @gmeroni you see in particular we would never have guessed you were loading the `cases` package (which I have never heard of) since `cases` is a standard amsmath command so any answers based on your original fragment would likely have been wrong

Comment: not relevant to this question, but `amsmath` automatically loads `amstext`, so it's not necessary to load it separately.

Comment: related question: [Separate labels in cases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951/579)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{subnumcases}{}\label{eq:regola_scelta_reject}
    \mbox{objective:}&$\displaystyle \qquad \min\sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j$\\
    \mbox{subject to:}  &$\displaystyle \qquad \sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j \geq W_L$\\[12pt]
     \xdef\theparentequation{\the\numexpr\theparentequation+1}%
     \setcounter{equation}{1}%
      \mbox{objective:}&$\displaystyle \qquad \min \sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j \vee H_{e} \geq 2$ \\  
    \mbox{subject to:}  &$\displaystyle \qquad \sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j < W_L$ \label{eq:regola_scelta_reject_2}
\end{subnumcases}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to split in two part? I'd have (1a),(1b) and (2a),(2b) since I need to reference the two knapsack problem separately.

Comment: @gmeroni see update

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: What comment are you replying to :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks but the outcome is [this](http://cl.ly/image/1X1U3D2L2L2Y/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-14%20at%2009.33.38.png). I set the x.xx numbering.

Comment: @gmeroni The output of the code I posted above is as shown in the image I posted. If you have different input that isn't doing the right thing it is best to ask a _new_ question with a _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem. Not much I can do just looking at an image without knowing what made it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code suits your needs – if I've well understood. You need the `empheq` package (which loads `amsmath`), with th `overload`option, to have a simpler code:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage[overload]{empheq}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{align}[left = (R)\enspace\empheqlbrace]%\label{eq:regola_scelta_reject}\smash[t]\smash[b]
         &  \begin{alignedat}{2}\label{eq:regola_scelta_reject_1}
          &  \text{objective: } & &  \min \sum_{j=1}^{H} x_j w_j\\
           & \text{subject to: } &\qquad   & \sum_{j=1}^{\smash H} x_j w_j \geq W_L\\
         \end{alignedat}\\]
            &   \begin{alignedat}{2} \label{eq:regola_scelta_reject_2}
          &  \text{objective: } & &  \min  \sum_{j=1}^{H}x_jw_j \vee H_{e} \geq 2 \\
           & \text{subject to: } & \qquad  & \sum_{j=1}^{\smash H} x_jw_j < W_L
         \end{alignedat}\
        \end{align}

        \end{document}
```

Results in:
[image]

Note that you can't have a label for the align outer environment *and* for the inner alignedat environnments. I simulated a tag ((R)) for the outer align.

Comment: Thank you @bernard. Is there any way to label Objective and constraint separately like (1a) and (1b)?

Comment: In a simple way (I mean with pre-existing tools one just has to pick), I'm afraid not. The `subequations`environment does that, but it does not work with nested environments like aligned and such. If I find something, I'll update my answer

Comment: `mathtools` also loads `amsmath`.  don't know whether this affects the `[overload]` option to `empheq`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: actually, `empheq` loads `mathtools`, hence `amsmath`. It's just that I used a minimal template that loads mathtools, and I forgot to cleanup my code on adding empheq.