# Multiple labels

Tags: align

I have been using the following piece of latex code

```
\begin{equation} \Phi(A_n) = \left \{
\begin{aligned}
    &\max \left [ L_n-A_n, 0 \right]\\
    &\max \left [ L_n-A_n, K \right]\label{eq:PayoffStopLosses}\\
    &\max \left [ L_n-A_n, K_1 \right] -\max \left [ A_n-L_n, K_2 \right]
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
```

to get the following result:
[image]

Now, I need to add a label to each expressions, and of course I got the error 'Multiple label'. I looked at some solutions, but they deal with set of equations without the big curl parenthesis.

Can you help on this?

Many thanks,

Andrea

Comment: see [Separate labels in cases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951/579)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please check the posting that @barbarabeeton has provided a link to and let us know if one or more of the suggested answers help you meet your objective as well.

Comment: @user52603: I've added a variant to one of the answers in the above mentioned thread.