# Separate labels in cases to then reference

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, cases

How can I label each of these equations separately so that I can refer to each of them later on?

```
\[
  \begin{cases}
  u_t+uu_x=-p_x, \\
  H_t+(uH)_x=0, 
  \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases?rq=1 answers your question?