# Left brace in align environoment

Tags: equations, align, braces, cases

I would like to have a left brace around equations in the align environment. 
How can I do this?

(I would like to use this environment because I would like to number each individual equation to be able to refer to it.)

---

So my code looks like this, and I want to have a curly brace on the left around the the 3 equations.  How can I do this?

```
\begin{align}
& F= ma \\
& v= at \\
& W= F s
\end{align}
```

EDIT: I didn't want to use the empheq package, because I get the error ''empheq.sty'' not found.

Comment: @egreg See edit

Comment: Update your TeX distribution; the `empheq` package is several year old.

Comment: @egreg How can I do this? (I use texmaker)

Comment: On what platform? What TeX distribution? I suggest you to install a full TeX Live (or MiKTeX if you're on Windows and prefer this one).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases

Comment: @egreg Windows 7. Thanks; I will have a look at the link you provide

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't use an `align` environment for this job. Instead, I suggest you use the `empheq` package and its eponymous environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace]{align}
               F &= ma\\
               v &= at\\
               W &= Fs
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get the error ''empheq.sty not found'' if I try to compile your code. How can I fix this?

Comment: I already tried to put the file empheq.sty in the folder I compile into. But this didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: @Bernard I compile with Texmaker. (Does this answer your  question? I don't know exactly what you mean with distribution..)

Comment: @student441 - TeXmaker is the front end, not the TeX program itself. A TeX distribution would be something like TeXLive or MikTeX.

Comment: @student441 See http://www.seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html

Comment: @student441 Package `empheq` is part of `mathtools`, which is available both in TeX Live and MiKTeX.

Comment: @Mico one question: if I want to *not* have the equation tags (i.e. '(1)', '(2)', '(3)' in this case), what should I do?

Comment: Ah problem solved @Mico , turns out I just need to write align* !

Comment: @JpW - Using an `empheq` environment if the equations needn't be numbered individually is probably overkill. Try something like `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} \[ \left\{ \begin{aligned} F &= ma\\ v &= at\\ W &= Fs \end{aligned} \right. \] \end{document}`.