# How to get a vectors components be a labeled equation?

Tags: cross-referencing, align

Basically I would like to have the following in a single line instead of the line break right before `\begin{alignat}`

```
$\begin{pmatrix}
component1 \\ component2
\end{pmatrix}=$\begin{alignat}{2}
0 \label{eq:first}\\    
0 \label{eq:second}
\end{alignat}
```

So, how can I use a vectors components to reference/label it like an equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31957/55879) to this context. It seems a bit hacky, but appears to do the job, and even works with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mymatrix}
\begin{align} \sbox{\mymatrix}{$\displaystyle
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathit{component}_1 \\ \mathit{component}_2
    \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1ex} = \hspace{2ex}
$}\raisebox{-.5\ht\mymatrix}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox{\mymatrix}}
    0 \label{eggs} \\
    0 \label{wine}
\end{align}
Now, I refer to \eqref{eggs} and \eqref{wine}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to place delimiters around the second vector, you can place the entire equation into the `\mymatrix` box and blank space into the second part, as follows:

```
\newsavebox{\mymatrix}
\begin{align} \sbox{\mymatrix}{$\displaystyle
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathit{component}_1 \\ \mathit{component}_2
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0
    \end{pmatrix}
$}\raisebox{-.5\ht\mymatrix}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox{\mymatrix}}
 \label{eggs} \\
 \label{wine}
\end{align}
```

This method is a little cleaner, and might be better even if you don't want to delimit the second vector.

[image]