# Separate numbering of cases within align

Tags: numbering, align, cases

I have one instance of `cases` within the `align` environment, as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x) &=1x \\
g(x) &=\begin{cases}
2 x \label{eq:g_1} \\
3 x 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

How can I number the different `cases` separately, thus having the numbering (1) for the first equation, (2a) and (2b) for the two cases?
Adding a second label within cases as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x) &=1x \\
g(x) &=\begin{cases}
2 x \label{eq:g_1} \\
3 x \label{eq:g_2}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

produces the amsmath package error: multiple \label's.
Of course a solution with `array` instead of `cases`, or any other alternative, works as well.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Basi.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951