# numbering each equation in cases

Tags: equations, cases

I want to add numbering to each equation below:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

$$
\Sigma F=ma:
\begin{cases}
 for(M): M\ddot x_1&=-kx_1+T-2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_1 \\
for(3m): 3m\ddot x_2&=F_2-T\\
for(m): m\ddot x_3&=-c\dot x-3-3kx_3+2k(x_1-x_3-r\theta)+F_3
\end{cases}
$$

\end{document}
```

I want the numbers to be 1,2 and 3 not 1.a,1.b and 1.c

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104202/14757 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325158/14757

Comment: And don't use `$$... $$` in latex

Comment: The first example of the accepted [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31956/16967) for the duplicate [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases) shows the numbering with 1 and 2 via environment `numcases`.