# Add tag number in array OR add left \{ in eqnarray

Tags: equations

My actual code is

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\mathscr{S}_1 
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
  u'(t) & = & -100u(t) + 25  \\
  u(0) &  = & 1
\end{array} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

But I don't know how to have numbers (1) an (2) for the 2 lines and keep the `\left\{` command.

I also tried this code :

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
  \label{eq:f}
  f(x) &=& \cases{x,&if \( x>0 \)\cr -x,&if \( x\le 0 \)\cr}\\
  \label{eq:g}
  g(x) &=& \cases{\sin(x),&if \( -1<x<1 \)\cr
  \cos(1-x),&otherwise.\cr}
\end{eqnarray}



\end{document}
```

But only I have one number per system, and I want one number per line.

PS : This is my first time on stackexchange and I didn't find out how to write compiled code, sorry for that ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We do not even want compiled code, that's fine. But one improvement would be to help us help you be extending your code to a compilable version (MWE).

Comment: okay you mean adding the packages and \begin{document} etc ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases/31956#31956

Comment: There is no on-site compilation of code, so any images you see in posts here are typically screenshots of a PDF generated by the person who wrote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By help of `empheq` package is easy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
u'(t) & =  -100u(t) + 25  \\
u(0)  & =   1
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```