# How to add a left bracket in subequations environment while keeping the equation number displayed

Tags: labels, brackets, subequations

There are three equations to be edited, where each of them need an equation label. Besides, the latter two ones need to gathered by a left bracket {. The final result is like this:

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31956/156366 <-- Does this (partially) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cases` (or `dcases`) environment within the `align` environment. You'll need both `amsmath` and `mathtools` packages. Like below:

```
\begin{align}
    \textrm{max } A & \\
    \textrm{s.t.} &
    \begin{dcases}
        B = C \\
        E = F
    \end{dcases}
\end{align}
```

This will give you equation numbers like (1) and (2). Not sure how to get (1.1) and (1.2). Check this for more info: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Comment: It is better to use \max instead of \mathrm{max }, and \textnormal instead of \textrm (or just \text if you want it to match the surrounding text). You can use \numberwithin{equation}{section} to produce the desired numbering format.