# Add text on left side of an empheq environment with a brace

Tags: math-mode, align, empheq

I wanted to write my equations with a left brace and text on the side left to my equations so I first used this code :

```
\[
\text{Sous contraintes}\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    eq1 & conditions1\\
    eq2 & conditions2\\
    eq3 & conditions3\\
    \end{array}
    \right.
\]
```

[image: Use of align but not numebered]

However, I also need my equations to be numbered, so I tried empheq environment :

```
\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace]{align}
    eq1 && conditions1\\
    eq2 && conditions2\\
    eq3 && conditions3
\end{empheq}
```

[image: Use of empeq but can't add text before brace]

Which works for the numbered equations.

But I couldn't manage to add « Sous contraintes » (under constraints) on the left of my equations.
How can I do this ?
Morever, if « contraintes » could be just under « sous » (on a new line, but still on the left of the brace), it'll be perfect !

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Hi J.Khamphousone. I think this might help you with your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases If I find the time I will see to compile a complete working example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to the `left=` key:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left =\text{Sous contraintes} \empheqlbrace]{align}
eq1 && conditions1\\
eq2 && conditions2\\
eq3 && conditions3
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by @BambOo, you might want to number the conditions as 1a, 1b, 1c, nest  the environment in  `subequations`.

Another possibility is the `numcases` or `subnumcases` environment:

```
\usepackage{cases}
..................
\begin{subnumcases}{\text{Sous contraintes}}
eq1 & conditions1\\
eq2 & conditions2\\
eq3 & conditions3
\end{subnumcases}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard ! That works perfectly. I added `\parbox{8em}{Sous \\ contraintes}` so the two words can be superposed

Comment: You might want to have a 1.a, 1.b, 1.c numbering of your equations, in this case, wrap your `empheq` environment inside a `subequations` environment.

Comment: It's indeed a better way of numbering, thank you @BambOo