# Equation with cases and numbering and including text

Tags: numbering, cases, subequations, text-manipulation

I am trying to create cases in the equation with numbering to individual cases and trying to push the text which is in \mbox{...} to the right. But I wasn't able to succeed. I request your kind help and suggestions on the same. Thank you very much for your help in advance. Kindly the refer the below figure for better understanding visually.

Thanks and Regards,
Arjun[image: Current Latex Output]

```
\begin{equation}
 d_{50} = 
  \begin{cases}
    \left(\frac{18\eta U_{r0}}{\rho_p U_{\theta0}^2}\right)^{1/2} \frac{r}{r_0^{1/2}} = C\frac{r}{r_0^{1/2}}   \mbox{ m=1(Free vortex)}\\
    \label{Eq:DpCFreV}

    \left(\frac{18\eta U_{r0}}{\rho_p U_{\theta0}^2}\right)^{1/2} \frac{r_0^{3/2}}{r} =   C\frac{r_0^{3/2}}{r}   \mbox{ m=-1(Forced vortex)}
    \label{Eq:DpCForcV}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Does this help: [Separate labels in `cases`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951) ?  As for space before the text, precede it by `&`, which will align the conditions to the right.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can do that easily with the `cases` package, which defines a `numcases` and a `subnumcases` environment, depending on the type of numbering you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{ d_{50} =}
\left(\frac{18\eta U_{r0}}{\rho_p U_{\theta0}^2}\right)^{1/2} \frac{r}{r_0^{1/2}} = C\frac{r}{r_0^{1/2}} &\quad $ m = 1 $ (Free vortex) 
\label{Eq:DpCFreV}\\
\left(\frac{18\eta U_{r0}}{\rho_p U_{\theta0}^2}\right)^{1/2} \frac{r_0^{3/2}}{r} = C\frac{r_0^{3/2}}{r} &\quad $ m=-1 $ (Forced vortex) 
\label{Eq:DpCForcV}
\end{numcases}

\begin{subnumcases}{ d_{50} =}
\left(\frac{18\eta U_{r0}}{\rho_p U_{\theta0}^2}\right)^{1/2} \frac{r}{r_0^{1/2}} = C\frac{r}{r_0^{1/2}} &\quad $ m = 1 $ (Free vortex)
\label{Eq:DpCFreV}\\
\left(\frac{18\eta U_{r0}}{\rho_p U_{\theta0}^2}\right)^{1/2} \frac{r_0^{3/2}}{r} = C\frac{r_0^{3/2}}{r} &\quad $ m=-1 $ (Forced vortex)
\label{Eq:DpCForcV}
\end{subnumcases}
```

\end{document}
[image]

Comment: Hi Bernard,
Thank you very much for the suggestion.
I have copied the same code into my editor. But surprisingly d_{50} is missing in the output. Any help here. I am running the code on overleaf.

Comment: It is working for numcases. But it is not working for subnumcases(D_50) is not printing in the output.

Comment: Hi @Bernard,  Is it possible to add more space for text printing in the same line(Extreme right)?

Comment: Strande that it doesn't work. Does just the minimalistic code I posted work? I suspect you have a conflicting package, so  a minimal code reproducing the problem would be welcome. For the spacing problem, is it from  m=1 or from the text between parentheses?