# Trying to write optimization formulas, but I can't seem to align part of the restrictions

Tags: align

In the following optimization problem:

```
\begin{align}
\text{Minimize} \quad
& \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j x_j \\
\text{s.t.} \quad
& \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{ij} x_j \geq 1 \quad i = 1 \ldots m \\
& \sum_{j=1}^{n} g_{kj} x_j \leq h_k \quad k = 1 \ldots K \\
& x_j \in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}
\end{align}
```

I would like to align

```
i = 1 \ldots m
k = 1 \ldots K
```

so they are similar to this:

[image]

I'm using \quad as a suggestion from ChatGPT. Any advice here will be extremely welcome and valuable.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx.

Comment: Since you're using `align`, replace the `\quqd` by `&&`.  You might benefit from reading about this in the `amsmath` users guide.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the alignment via `&`.

Personally, I would not use any `\quad` but you may add them. In addition, I added commas. But these are just my recommendations. You might also want to have a look on https://ctan.org/pkg/lshort.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31956/128553 for a different numbering scheme within the cases environment.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{Minimize } 
    & \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j x_j \\
\text{s.t. } 
    & \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{ij} x_j \geq 1,         & i = 1, \ldots, m, \\
    & \sum_{j=1}^{n} g_{kj} x_j \leq h_k,       & k = 1, \ldots, K, \\
    & x_j \in \left \{ 0, 1 \right \}.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{Minimize } 
    & \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j x_j \\
\text{s.t. } 
    & \begin{cases}
        \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{ij} x_j \geq 1,         & i = 1, \ldots, m, \\
        \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} g_{kj} x_j \leq h_k,       & k = 1, \ldots, K, \\
        \displaystyle x_j \in \left \{ 0, 1 \right \}.
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{Minimize } 
    & \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j x_j \\
\text{s.t. } 
    & \begin{cases}
        \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{ij} x_j \geq 1,       & i &= 1, \ldots, m, \\
        \sum_{j=1}^{n} g_{kj} x_j \leq h_k,         & k &= 1, \ldots, K, \\
        x_j \in \left \{ 0, 1 \right \}.
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]