# How can I create a list of equations in an equation environment?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, labels

I am trying to create something like this in `amsart` document class:

[image: List of equations in an equation environment]

where I can label and access the individual equations through the `\label` and `\ref` commands.

I have tried various combinations of the `align`, `equation`, `aligned`, `cases`, and `array` environments, but either I am making a mistake (which is very likely) or it is more complicated than I thought.

I sincerely hope that someone among you can help me in some way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question might help: [Separate labels in `cases`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate labels in cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\label` and `\ref`  are used for counters, specifically the last occurance of `\refstepcounter`.  However, `equation` redefines `\label` to always return the equation number.

This uses a new counter (case) to generate the case numbers so that `\label` can record them. It also uses `\normallabel`, which is simply `\label` as defined outside the equation environment.

I put the parenthesis inside `\thecase` for simplicity.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{amsart}

\newcounter{case}[equation]% reset to 0
\renewcommand{\thecase}{\textrm{(\roman{case})}}
\let\normallabel=\label

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
  \refstepcounter{case}\hfil\thecase\normallabel{first} & first\\
  \refstepcounter{case}\hfil\thecase\normallabel{second} & second\\
  \refstepcounter{case}\hfil\thecase\normallabel{third} & third
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
See cases \ref{first}, \ref{second} and \ref{third}.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]